# Setting boundries for a div that floats on top of a web page and moves as the viewer scrolls down

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-float, accordion

I have a float-with-the-scroll div on the right hand side of my page, and I would like to set bounderies for it, but it shares the page with text and buttons that open in a jquery vertical accordion style with tabs of uneven length. Therefore, the bottom of the page is not a set number, and the div ends up on top of the footer when the page is scrolled all the way down. Also, if the page gets resized the box gets knocked out of place. Is there a way to define that it should not go past certain other divs on the page? Here is the css I have for the div:

```
position: fixed;
width:225px;
float:right;
margin-left:1em;
top: 36.5%;
left: 65%;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 5px;
```

[jsFiddle - the issue is with the blue box and the text that goes with it](http://jsfiddle.net/9P8n7/1)

A good example of the scrolling div is the "Summary" box found on [Apple's configurator page](http://store.apple.com/us_smb_78313/configure/MD772LL/A?=)

Comment: Please put together a jsFiddle.

Comment: please avoid the use of the term "floater" :)

Comment: please provide some visual example of what you need

Comment: @Eliran Malka
Use of the term "Floater" has been removed.

Comment: @E L Visual example: Is the jsFiddle and link to the Adobe site good, or should I add screenshots?